# How do I add optional functionality to a class?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently trying to learn the ins and outs of XNA/C# but I'm currently stuck on a problem: I want to add optional functionality to a class and I have no idea how to even start. For clarity, here is my current code:

```
public class Actor
{
    //Fields
    private Vector3 m_location;

    //Properties
    public Vector3 Location
    {
        get { return m_location; }
        set { m_location = value; }
    }

    //Constructors
    public Actor(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        Location = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
    public Actor(Vector3 location)
    {
        Location = location;
    }
}

public class Actor2D : Actor
{
    //Fields
    private Texture2D m_texture;

    //Properties
    public Texture2D Texture
    {
        get { return m_texture; }
        set { m_texture = value; }
    }

    //Constructors
    public Actor2D(float x, float y, float z) : base(x, y, z) {}
    public Actor2D(Vector3 vector) : base(vector) {}

    //Methods
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Vector2(Location.X, Location.Y), Color.White);
    }
    public void Load(ContentManager content, string asset)
    {
        Texture = content.Load<Texture2D>(asset);
    }
}
```

The logic here is that all Actors have to have a location but they don't necessarily have to have a texture as an Actor could be a light source, trigger, etc etc. Actor2D is similar in this except that it's designated as an Actor that uses 2D texture. What I want to do is have the ability to add functionality to either of these classes on an as needed basis. Say I want the Actor2D to be animated or as mentioned earlier I want to add a trigger or light source to an untextured Actor... What are some ideas that would help me accomplish these goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bunch of thinking and searching on Google/StackOverflow. I've finally found my answer. Rather than using a traditional OOP approach I learned that I should be using a more Component-Oriented Programming approach. I found a really great link at Component based game engine design.

Of particular interest is the 5-part series on T=Machine describing Entity Systems which seems to be an approach which does exactly what I was looking for. For those interested, the first post is: http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/.

Answer (score 3):

You could try taking a look at the [decorator pattern](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_wrapper302122006080905AM/csharp_wrapper3.aspx), which allows you to 'tack on' behaviour to an object.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I apologize for not being as clear as I should have. I definitely want the ability to "tack on" traits but I do not want to do it with Inheritance or Interfaces because I want the classes to be as basic as possible and I would have to do a recompile every time I wanted to add a particular "power" to a class.

I really want to be able to "tack on" these traits at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want object "morphing" as in objects changing their set of methods at runtime, you're looking at [mixins](http://remix.codeplex.com/). (tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192716/re-mix-A-Mixin-Library-for-NET)) 
**Fair warning:** it is not for the faint hearted.

Now since at compile-time you know all the types that will have to be available, use a variety of interfaces:

- IHasTexture
- IDrawable : IHasTexture (this means and IDrawable automatically has to implement IHasTexture, since you can't draw otherwise)
- ILoadable
- ... as many as you want.

Then provide an implementation for each combination you need. Furthermore, I think it would be best to put all this in your business layer if you have any.

Hope this helps,

Bab.

EDIT: example.

```
public interface IMovable { void Move(); }

public class MoveMixin : IMovable
{
   public void Move() { Console.WriteLine("I am moving"); }
}

public class SomeDude { }

public static class TestClass
{
   public static Test()
   {
      var myMixinConfiguration = MixinConfiguration.BuildFromActive()
           .ForClass<SomeDude>().AddMixin<MoveMixin>()
           .BuildConfiguration();
      using(myMixinConfiguration.EnterScope())
      {//In this scope, SomeDude implements IMovable, but only if you get an instance through the ObjectFactory
         var myMovableDude = ObjectFactory.Create<SomeDude>(ParamList.Empty);
         ((IMovable)myMovableDude).Move(); //This line compiles and executes just fine, even though the class declaration does not specify anything about Move() !!
      }
      //The SomeDude class no longer implements IMovable
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bab but I'm really trying to avoid any outside libraries and that's still not quite what I'm after (close though). I want things as clean as possible and I want to an Actor2D to BE an Actor2D. I'm fine with all Actor2Ds having an "Animate()" method but I don't want the Fields/Properties required for that method to be stored in the class because it would waste unnecessary resources.

Comment: Mixins allow you to define a default implementation of an interface, and inject dynamically at runtime that bit of code. Your objects are still castable as themselves, they just grab an additional interface implementation. The code is entirely set in a different class (called the "Mixin"). Seems to me that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to read through the documentation and examples and it looked like I still had to declare say- Actor2D : IAnimated in order to define the functionality of the animation. Which makes sense because the game needs to know how exactly to perform the animation on the Actor2D. I guess I just don't really understand what's going on behind the scenes with the Mixin.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding things correctly here: the Mixin is basically just a less restrictive Interface in that I can actually define the implementation of the Mixin without doing so in the class?

Comment: @Kittoes In its essence, yes, exactly.Although you could build much more complex mixins that act upon the class they're mixed in to make the mixin's methods adapt themselves to their host. That's not for tonight ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `Actor2D` (and its likes) derived from `Actor`. Just change those derived classes to classes of their own, and, have one class (-`Actor`) for every "Actor" with *all* of those properties. (An `Actor2D` property...) Then use whichever you need at runtime.

They will not take up that much resources because they will be pointing to `null`'s when not used.

EDIT:

```
class Actor
{
    public Stuff2D stuff2d = new Stuff2D();
    public StuffLightPower lightPower = new StuffLightPower();
    //...
}

class Stuff2D
{
    public int height;
    public int weight;
    //...
}

class StuffLightPower
{
    public int lumen;
    public Color color;
    //...
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Actor actor1 = new Actor();

//First it's going to be a 2D.
actor1.stuff2d.weight = 3;
//...

//Now it's changed to a light source.
actor1.stuff2d = null;
actor1.lightPower.color = Color.White;
//...

//And back again.
actor1.lightPower = null;
actor1.stuff2d = new Stuff2D();
//...
```

Comment: Could you please further elaborate on what you mean here.

Comment: See edit.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ (You don't really need the `null`'s. they're just for if you want to use less resources.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's actually really helpful. Now... there's no reason that it couldn't be both a Light Source AND a 2D Texture is there?

Comment: Nope. Whatever you want. And by the way, your methods seem to be able to be made static.

Comment: My only problem with this is that it's not very "clean." You see, I'm quite the minimalist and one of the things that REALLY turned me off about working on the UDK is the shear amount of variables and options that their Actor class has. While it allowed you do to a lot of stuff it wasn't very intuitive and required you to know exactly what each variable controlled and where they were. I'm trying to avoid that "burden of knowledge." Is there any way I can make this a bit more "friendly" without losing power/flexibility that you could think of?

Comment: @Kittoes I don't know about XNA but do you really need to know all the options? Can't you just use what you want and ignore the rest? As for C#, you can streamline my example by a) Not setting anything to `null` (are your resources really that limited?) and b) Eliminating all the extra classes, and putting all of the fields directly in `Actor`. Also, create methods in whatever is your main class (and make them static) except for what you can't.

Comment: The reason I need to know all of the options is because of how I want to design my project. I've had this idea rolling around in my head for a long time about designing my game sort of like a set of Legos. For example: a player is composed of an Actor, 3D Texture, Movement, Physics, Abilities, etc. A box however is simply an Actor, 3D Texture, and maybe Physics. Each object is composed of a varying amount of traits and I want the ability to piece those together at will. Since "objects" are composed of "pieces" then I don't need to recompile every time I want a new type of actor.